Central simple regression

I derived $$\sigma^2 + \sigma^2 \cdot \frac{\sum_{i=n_1}^{n} x_i^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{n_1} x_i^2} \cdot \frac{1}{n - n_1}$$
Is this expression correct?
